# Merging Raster Datasets of Different Resolutions using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, resolution

I am using ArcGIS Desktop.

I have two DEMs in .tif format and I am looking to merge the two. The main problem with merging these are that they are different resolutions (one is 10m and one is ~20m). Also, another problem with merging the two is that they overlap and I am not sure of the most effective way of dealing with that overlap. Obviously I want to keep the values of the better resolution.

So what are the best methods here?

- Is there a python script available that works best with merging rasters? I would like to automate this with a script if possible.
- Which process of resampling is best for DEM data? Bipolar, Cubic... ?
- What is the best way to merge overlapping DEMs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Question 1*

The attached script mosaics a list of rasters into a new raster dataset.  Make sure to specify "MINIMUM" if you would like to maintain your 10m resolution raster datasets.

*Question 2*

Bilinear interpolation and cubic convolution are both good choices for resampling continuous data.  Nearest neighbor is best for discrete raster datasets.  Keep in mind that resampling a 30m resolution DEM to 10m will not improve the quality of the DEM, but rather will create more pixels that represents 30m resolution.

*Question 3*

The [Mosaic to New Raster (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000098000000) tool is your best choice.

---

You can see Mosaic to New Raster does a great job at merging overlapping rasters and color balancing.
[image]

---

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set overwrite
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1

# Set environment
env.workspace = r'C:\temp'
Dir = env.workspace

# Produce a list of raster datasets
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()
list = ";".join(rasters)

# Raster to new mosaic
output = "new_dem" 
arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(list,Dir, output, "", "", "", 1, "MINIMUM")
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I think the bug is gone now. It produced a tif for me just fine.

Comment: Are you sure your two DEMs are spatially coincident?  If in doubt, consider using the *Mosaic to New Raster* tool's Environments > Processing Extent > Snap Raster setting, using one of the two rasters as the snap raster.  This will assure that the other raster will be adjusted in X-Y coordinate space (ie, "snapped") to spatially align with the snap raster.  I don't know how to implement this in Python, maybe someone else can speak to that.

Comment: Very late comment but in case anyone reads this and tries to combine DEMs _before_ any analysis __DONT__. As was pointed out in the answer, if you resample your 30 m DEM to 10 m you will get multiple cells of the same value covering the original, larger cell. This will make e.g. slope calculations, very wrong; you may typically see terraces in the results. The sensor or survey was/should have been designed with a particular GSD. Analysis should be performed at this original GSD.

Answer (score 0):

Look into mosaics for the overlapping issue.

For the resolution, look into resampling.

These can be done different ways depending on which platform, software, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that I am working in ArcGIS Desktop for this.