# Integrate (or merge) raster with different resolution

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I need to integrate two raster layers: the first is a land cover raster  (grid format) at 300m resolution and the 2nd is the Population raster (grid format) at 1km resolution. I need to integrate the land cover raster dataset with the information on population density from the second raster, which has a lower resolution and gets one output raster.

Do you think is it possible to integrate or merge them in one raster with the higher resolution?

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'integrate'? Do you plan to compare the datasets in some way or calculate some stats/relationships between them? Ultimately, you can not increase the resolution of the 1km raster. You can resample it to the 300m but you will not get any additional information - you will have the same value over a 1km area but represented as numerous 300m pixels. This answer may be of help to you: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58693/how-to-merge-raster-datasets-of-different-resolutions?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If you meant by integration to stack the two raster layers to have them displayed in RGB color composite, then you need to resample the 1km resolution to 300 m resolution, because stacking two images with different resolution is not possible. To resample the raster image you need to use [Resample tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/resample.htm), then [Composite Bands](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/composite-bands.htm). However, it is better to have 3 images to use composite bands tool since this will allow you to display them in RGB color composite.

If you meant by integration to have their attribute table combined to create a new raster data with combined attributes of both raster data, then you need to use [Combine tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/combine.htm) which requires Spatial Analyst. It also requires the raster data to be resampled.